# Capturar datos de un solo TR jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo que una tabla dinamica y dentro tengo un td con un boton con dropdown con varias opciones en ( una es guardar ) que seria especificamente capturar la informacion en especifico de ese tr y enviarlo por ajax alguna idea de como capturar solo la informacion de dicho tr ?.

Comment: Debes incluir más información, quizás un pequeño ejemplo de código para que veamos el problema. Te recomiendo que leas sobre cómo crear un [mcve] en el centro de ayuda para más información. Y revisa la documentación de jQuery para [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) porque podrá serte útil.

Answer (score 1):

Esto debería ayudarte.

```js
$( "select" ).change(function() {
  if(this.value == "guardar"){
    
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var nombre1 = tr.find('td').eq(0).text();
    var nombre2 = tr.find('td').eq(1).text();
    
    console.log(nombre1);
    console.log(nombre2);
    
    //envias los datos por ajax
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>nombre1</td>
    <td>nombre2</td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="">seleccione algo</option>
        <option value="guardar">Guardar</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="">seleccione algo</option>
        <option value="guardar">Guardar</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```